# How to set permanent macro in VScode vim？

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, macros

I want to **set permanent macros in VScode vim**, but **as soon as my mac restarts, the previous macro will be clear**. Though I can set permanent macros in terminal vim and it is valid after my mac restarts, I also want to know if VScode vim can support this function because I take VScode as my main vim editor.

Answer (score 3):

[saving macros #2380](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2380)

At this point I don't think this feature is available; but there are workarounds mentioned in the issue. Also:

> @fredyonge In the next version you'll be able to save registers across sessions, but there are still some major issues that need to be figured out before it'll work for macros as well.